# Old Hat and black top bar

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2013

Ok, so I'm being really picky, but those two white pixels on the "Old Hat" hat clash somewhat with the black top bar (as the rest of the hat outline is also black):

[image: Black Hat, Black Top Bar]

(The other two light pixels are my fault as they're the background of my gravatar).

Yes, I know I could change my hat, but I haven't got around to earning any I'd prefer yet!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, no matter what color you choose for a hat, it will clash with *some* part of the UI since gravatars are everywhere.

Better to clash with the topbar where only you can see it.

Comment: Its just a shame that it rather despoils the lovely new top bar in particular (which I'm a big fan of by the way)